Using klib to analyze a dataset csv file
I have my dataset as a csv file on my desktop. I launched a jupyter notebook and now i want to read my csv file in jupyter and i can´t figure out how to do that. I typed in:
import panda as pd
dataset = pd.read.csv("C:\users\XXX\Desktop\file.csv")

However, I get a SyntaxError.
I tried finding out how to convert my csv file into something different and I could not manage to find out how to do that.

What is the syntax error? It should be included in the post along with code you ran, preferably formatted? For example, without the error text, I cannot tell if you actually ran import panda as pd and got a syntax error or if the error was to the other line. Please read the guide How do I ask a good question?, especially the section 'Help others reproduce the problem' and the bullet point in an earlier section 'Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague' where it tells you to include the error.

Related: often new users on Windows machines have trouble with file paths because they can be a little more trickier than Unix-based systems which are what a lot of examples reference, see here and here and here. Often it is easier to put the file, or a copy of it, alongside the Jupyter Notebook file and just use the file name. Also be aware that the use of OneDrive can make files seem one place on Windows when they are not.

add r before the path pd.read.csv(r"C:\users\XXX\Desktop\file.csv")

The r helped. Thank you very much!

Does this answer your question? How should I write a Windows path in a Python string literal?

Shouldn't that read call be pd.read_csv with an underscore?
